# Defining a constant/declaring an array

Tags: c++

I am trying to declare two arrays, one 2D and one 1D. I know the dimensions need to be const values. So the const value is assigned from the return value of a function call. That goes well, but when I use the derived value to declare the array, COMPILE errors! WHY???

Here is my code:

```
int populateMatrixFromFile(string fname) {
std::ifstream fileIn;
int s = determineDimensions(fname);  // return value  (CONST INT)
const int size = s;                  // assign to const

cout << "Value returned from determineDimensions(): " << size << endl;

if (size > 10){
    cout << "Maximum dimensions for array is 10 rows and 10 columns. Exiting" << endl;
    return 1;
}

fileIn.open(fname.c_str(), ios::in); //opened for reading only.

float aMatrix[size][size];  // ERROR
float bMatrix[size];        // ERROR
```

BUT it works here:

```
    // assign the pth row of aMatrix to temp

    const int alen = sizeof (aMatrix[p]) / sizeof (float);
    float temp[alen];                                    // WORKS!!!

    for (size_t i = 0; i < alen; i++) {
        temp[i] = aMatrix[p][i];
    }
```

Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler enforces this rule about a constant size of an array because it allocates the needed memory at compile time. In otherwords, all values needed to calculate the size of the array must be known at compile-time. In your first example, this is not the case, so the compiler complains.

If you really need to have dynamically sized arrays, you should use pointers and the new[] operator to allocate the array. You will also need to remember to use the delete[] operator to return the memory to the system and avoid any memory leaks.

Comment: You *should* use `std::vector`.

Comment: @chris Certainly that is another alternative as long as there are no other constraints such as this being a classroom assignment where std::vector is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The size of the second dimension, third, etc. in any array is always constant. Period. The standard is very clear about this.

The first dimension (actually the last index) can be variable if you allocate variable on the heap with array form of new, like this:

```
int size = 50;
float *p = new float[size];

.... do stuffs

delete[] p;
```

Some compilers allow variable sized arrays on the stack, but it is better not to use this.

Comment: So I can remove the 1st dim value? I tried that and it did not work.

Comment: If you want a matrix, you can't. You can implement calculating index in the matrix yourself. In many cases this is not difficult.

Comment: How do you implement that? Thanks.